# Raster to polygon with RGB composite using Arcgis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, polygon, rgb, composite

I am trying to convert an RGB composite to a shapefile to use with. The raster to polygon function returns with three shapefiles with "grid_code" of the value of each of these three channels. I am wondering if there are easier ways to combine them into one shapefile with a unique value for each color? Or can I do anything to transform the RGB composite raster into one that contains a unique value for each color before the raster to polygon exercise?

Edit: I have a raster of world solar intensity consisting of about 10 colors which indicates the solar intensity categories of pixles. The raster is in RGB composite form. What I want to do is to create a polygon shapefile out of this raster. However the shapefile generated by raster to polygon function of arcgis contains only information on R channel.

Comment: I checked the three shapefiles, they seem to be identical, so I am a bit puzzled now....I guess the question is how to convert an RGB composite raster into polygons with a unique value representing one color?

Comment: what is the actual number of pixel values that you expect. The number of colors quickly becomes huge : e.g. 255*255*255 > 16 million. But maybe you already visualize a classified image, which is a different problem. Could you provide more information ? (you can press the "edit" below your post to add more information)

Comment: Thanks a lot! The problem can be easily solved by combine (by spatial analyst) followed by raster to polygon.